# Trouble Getting Numerical Integration Working in Julia

Tags: julia, differential-equations

I'm trying to get a moderately large system of differential equations to integrate using the DifferentialEquations.jl package in Julia and my integration is crashing after a couple seconds.

I know one strategy to begin debugging is to break up the system and that can be done here becuase there are some seperation of time scales. In doing that though -- I introduced other errors. So I'm not sure what to try.

My only hint is that `integ.k` has some large values and an `NaN`. I know this is a big block of code, but it should crash immediately. Does anyone see what's happening?

```
######################################################################################

using DifferentialEquations, NaNMath

endd = 20000000.0

#####################################################################
### Parameters

## Sensor Parameters
alphaOffset = .045;
GF =  53;
GS =  3;
GD =  1.0;
gamma = 10e-7;
delta = 10e-4;
sensorFuseDelta = .001;

## Targets
FBar = .25;
SBar = .03; 
DBar = .02;

## Homeostatic Time Scales
tauG = 4000.0;
tauHalfac = 2100.0;
tauS = 2000.0;
tauAlpha = 2000.0;

## Reversal Potentials
EK(t) = -80;
EH = -20.0;
ENa = 30.0;
EL = -50.0;

#####################################################################

### Define generic functions
## Generic Activation/Inactication Curves
sigmd(x,translate,center,reactance) = 1/(1+exp(((x-translate) + center)/reactance));
## Define the time constant function for ion channels
tauX(Volt, CT, DT, AT, BT, halfAc) = CT - DT/(1 + exp(((Volt-halfAc) + AT)/BT));
## Some intrinsic currents require a special time constant function
spectau(Volt, CT, DT, AT, BT, AT2, BT2, halfAc) = CT + DT/(exp(((Volt-halfAc) + AT)/BT) + exp(((Volt-halfAc) + AT2)/BT2));
## Define the ionic currents; q is the exponent of the activation variable m
iIonic(g, m, h, q, Volt, Erev) = g*(m^q)*h*(Volt - Erev);

#####################################################################

# Ion Channel Acitvation/Inactivation Curves
NaMinf(V,trns) = sigmd(V,trns, 25.5, -5.29);  # m^3
NaHinf(V,trns) = sigmd(V,trns, 48.9, 5.18);  # h
CaTMinf(V,trns) = sigmd(V,trns, 27.1, -7.20);  # m^3
CaTHinf(V,trns) = sigmd(V,trns, 32.1, 5.50);  # h
CaSMinf(V,trns) = sigmd(V,trns, 33.0, -8.1);  # m^3
CaSHinf(V,trns) = sigmd(V,trns, 60.0, 6.20);  # h
HMinf(V,trns) = sigmd(V,trns, 70.0, 6.0);  # m
KdMinf(V,trns) = sigmd(V,trns, 12.3, -11.8);  # m^4
KCaMinf(V,trns,IntCa) = (IntCa/(IntCa + 3.0))*sigmd(V,trns, 28.3, -12.6); # m^4
AMinf(V,trns) = sigmd(V,trns, 27.2, -8.70); # m^3
AHinf(V,trns) = sigmd(V,trns, 56.9, 4.90);  # h

# Time Constants (ms)
tauNaM(V,trns) = tauX(V, 1.32, 1.26, 120.0, -25.0, trns);
tauNaH(V,trns) = tauX(V, 0.00, -0.67, 62.9, -10.0, trns)*tauX(V, 1.50, -1.00, 34.9, 3.60, trns);
tauCaTM(V,trns) = tauX(V, 21.7, 21.3, 68.1, -20.5, trns);
tauCaTH(V,trns) = tauX(V, 105.0, 89.8, 55.0, -16.9, trns);
tauCaSM(V,trns) = spectau(V, 1.40, 7.00, 27.0, 10.0, 70.0, -13.0, trns);
tauCaSH(V,trns) = spectau(V, 60.0, 150.0, 55.0, 9.00, 65.0, -16.0, trns);
tauHM(V,trns) = tauX(V, 272.0, -1499.0, 42.2, -8.73, trns);
tauKdM(V,trns) = tauX(V, 7.20, 6.40, 28.3, -19.2, trns);
tauKCaM(V,trns) = tauX(V, 90.3, 75.1, 46.0, -22.7, trns);
tauAM(V,trns) = tauX(V, 11.6, 10.4, 32.9, -15.2, trns);
tauAH(V,trns) = tauX(V, 38.6, 29.2, 38.9, -26.5, trns);

# Calcium Reverse Potential
R = 8.314*1000.0;  # Ideal Gas Constant (*10^3 to put into mV)
temp = 10.0;  # Temperature in Celcius; Temperature of the Sea lawl
z = 2.0;  # Valence of Calcium Ions
Far = 96485.33;  # Faraday's Constant
CaOut = 3000.0;  # Outer Ca Concentration (uM)
ECa(CaIn) = ((R*(273.15 + temp))/(z*Far))*NaNMath.log(CaOut/CaIn);
#ECa(CaIn) = ((R*(273.15 + temp))/(z*Far))*log(CaOut/CaIn);

# Ionic Currents (mV / ms)
iNa(g,m,h,V) = iIonic(g, m, h, 3.0, V, ENa);
iCaT(g,m,h,V,CaIn) = iIonic(g, m, h, 3.0, V, ECa(CaIn));
iCaS(g,m,h,V,CaIn) = iIonic(g, m, h, 3.0, V, ECa(CaIn));
iH(g,m,V) = iIonic(g,  m, 1.0, 1.0, V, EH);
iKd(g,m,V,t) = iIonic(g, m, 1.0, 4.0, V, EK(t));
iKCa(g,m,V,t) = iIonic(g, m, 1.0, 4.0, V, EK(t));
iA(g,m,h,V,t) = iIonic(g, m, h, 3.0, V, EK(t));
iL(V) = iIonic(.01, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, V, EL);
iApp(t) = 0;

# Sensor Equations
F(FM,FH) = GF*FM^2*FH;
S(SM,SH) = GS*SM^2*SH;
D(DM)    = GD*DM^2; 
sensorFuse(EF,ES,ED) = exp(-(((EF/(sensorFuseDelta*12))^8 + (ES/(sensorFuseDelta*1.5))^8 + (ED/(sensorFuseDelta*.2))^8)^(1/8)));

############################################################################################

function f(du,u,p,t)
    du[1] = -iL(u[1])-iNa(u[14],u[2],u[3],u[1])-iCaT(u[15],u[4],u[5],u[1],u[13])-iCaS(u[16],u[6],u[7],u[1],u[13])-iH(u[17],u[8],u[1])-iKd(u[18],u[9],u[1],t)-iKCa(u[19],u[10],u[1],t)-iA(u[20],u[11],u[12],u[1],t)
    du[2]  = (NaMinf(u[1],u[21]) - u[2])/tauNaM(u[1],u[21])
    du[3]  = (NaHinf(u[1],u[22]) - u[3])/tauNaH(u[1],u[22])
    du[4]  = (CaTMinf(u[1],u[23]) - u[4])/tauCaTM(u[1],u[23])
    du[5]  = (CaTHinf(u[1],u[24]) - u[5])/tauCaTH(u[1],u[24])
    du[6]  = (CaSMinf(u[1],u[25]) - u[6])/tauCaSM(u[1],u[25])
    du[7]  = (CaSHinf(u[1],u[26]) - u[7])/tauCaSH(u[1],u[26])
    du[8]  = (HMinf(u[1],u[27]) - u[8])/tauHM(u[1],u[27])
    du[9]  = (KdMinf(u[1],u[28]) - u[9])/tauKdM(u[1],u[28])
    du[10] = (KCaMinf(u[1],u[29],u[13]) - u[10])/tauKCaM(u[1],u[29])
    du[11] = (AMinf(u[1],u[30]) - u[11])/tauAM(u[1],u[30])
    du[12] = (AHinf(u[1],u[31]) - u[12])/tauAH(u[1],u[31])
    du[13] = (-.94*(iCaT(u[15],u[4],u[5],u[1],u[13])+iCaS(u[16],u[6],u[7],u[1],u[13]))-u[13]+.05)/20
    du[14] = ((1*(FBar-F(u[32],u[33])) + 0*(SBar-S(u[34],u[35])) + 0*(DBar-D(u[36])))*u[14]-gamma*u[14]^3)*u[40]/tauG
    du[15] = ((0*(FBar-F(u[32],u[33])) + 1*(SBar-S(u[34],u[35])) + 0*(DBar-D(u[36])))*u[15]-gamma*u[15]^3)*u[40]/tauG
    du[16] = ((0*(FBar-F(u[32],u[33])) + 1*(SBar-S(u[34],u[35])) + 0*(DBar-D(u[36])))*u[16]-gamma*u[16]^3)*u[40]/tauG
    du[17] = ((0*(FBar-F(u[32],u[33])) + 1*(SBar-S(u[34],u[35])) + 1*(DBar-D(u[36])))*u[17]-gamma*u[17]^3)*u[40]/tauG
    du[18] = ((1*(FBar-F(u[32],u[33])) + -1*(SBar-S(u[34],u[35])) + 0*(DBar-D(u[36])))*u[18]-gamma*u[18]^3)*u[40]/tauG
    du[19] = ((0*(FBar-F(u[32],u[33])) + -1*(SBar-S(u[34],u[35])) + -1*(DBar-D(u[36])))*u[19]-gamma*u[19]^3)*u[40]/tauG
    du[20] = ((0*(FBar-F(u[32],u[33])) + -1*(SBar-S(u[34],u[35])) + -1*(DBar-D(u[36])))*u[20]-gamma*u[20]^3)*u[40]/tauG
    du[21] = ((-1*(FBar-F(u[32],u[33])) + 0*(SBar-S(u[34],u[35])) + 0*(DBar-D(u[36])))-delta*u[21]^3)*u[40]/tauHalfac
    du[22] = ((1*(FBar-F(u[32],u[33])) + 0*(SBar-S(u[34],u[35])) + 0*(DBar-D(u[36])))-delta*u[22]^3)*u[40]/tauHalfac
    du[23] = ((0*(FBar-F(u[32],u[33])) + -1*(SBar-S(u[34],u[35])) + 0*(DBar-D(u[36])))-delta*u[23]^3)*u[40]/tauHalfac
    du[24] = ((0*(FBar-F(u[32],u[33])) + 1*(SBar-S(u[34],u[35])) + 0*(DBar-D(u[36])))-delta*u[24]^3)*u[40]/tauHalfac
    du[25] = ((0*(FBar-F(u[32],u[33])) + -1*(SBar-S(u[34],u[35])) + 0*(DBar-D(u[36])))-delta*u[25]^3)*u[40]/tauHalfac
    du[26] = ((0*(FBar-F(u[32],u[33])) + 1*(SBar-S(u[34],u[35])) + 0*(DBar-D(u[36])))-delta*u[26]^3)*u[40]/tauHalfac
    du[27] = ((0*(FBar-F(u[32],u[33])) + -1*(SBar-S(u[34],u[35])) + -1*(DBar-D(u[36])))-delta*u[27]^3)*u[40]/tauHalfac
    du[28] = ((-1*(FBar-F(u[32],u[33])) + 1*(SBar-S(u[34],u[35])) + 0*(DBar-D(u[36])))-delta*u[28]^3)*u[40]/tauHalfac
    du[29] = ((0*(FBar-F(u[32],u[33])) + 1*(SBar-S(u[34],u[35])) + 1*(DBar-D(u[36])))-delta*u[29]^3)*u[40]/tauHalfac
    du[30] = ((0*(FBar-F(u[32],u[33])) + 1*(SBar-S(u[34],u[35])) + 1*(DBar-D(u[36])))-delta*u[30]^3)*u[40]/tauHalfac
    du[31] = ((0*(FBar-F(u[32],u[33])) + -1*(SBar-S(u[34],u[35])) + -1*(DBar-D(u[36])))-delta*u[31]^3)*u[40]/tauHalfac
    du[32] = (sigmd(iCaT(u[15],u[4],u[5],u[1],u[13])+iCaS(u[16],u[6],u[7],u[1],u[13]),0,14.8,1) - u[32])/.5
    du[33] = (sigmd(-1*(iCaT(u[15],u[4],u[5],u[1],u[13])+iCaS(u[16],u[6],u[7],u[1],u[13])),0,-9.8,1) - u[33])/1.5
    du[34] = (sigmd(iCaT(u[15],u[4],u[5],u[1],u[13])+iCaS(u[16],u[6],u[7],u[1],u[13]),0,7.2,1) - u[34])/50
    du[35] = (sigmd(-1*(iCaT(u[15],u[4],u[5],u[1],u[13])+iCaS(u[16],u[6],u[7],u[1],u[13])),0,-2.8,1) - u[35])/60
    du[36] = (sigmd(iCaT(u[15],u[4],u[5],u[1],u[13])+iCaS(u[16],u[6],u[7],u[1],u[13]),0,3,1) - u[36])/500
    du[37] = ((FBar - F(u[32],u[33])) - u[37])/tauS
    du[38] = ((SBar - S(u[34],u[35])) - u[38])/tauS
    du[39] = ((DBar - D(u[36])) - u[39])/tauS
    du[40] = (sigmd(-1*sensorFuse(u[37],u[38],u[39]),0,alphaOffset,-.001)-u[40])/tauAlpha
end

############################################################################################

#Start
ICs = [-29.337327051014498 0.387305560452983 0.520851480339422 0.15123291866400054 0.7788086343207855 0.18292525224066983 0.40518167654812637 0.40305741894377733 0.09880328448541692 0.1192742729813851 0.17090849597998528 0.4853554113680752 2.455375230646913 79.93706465236964 0.2873998785854699 0.0318308211031974 0.15906997203306664 99.67308490480416 0.8899609102246536 2.6818203693916858 -6.016940524541976 6.0497029078690145 -0.08934230228658809 0.1845828676421055 0.11586968152835098 0.7364356646257856 2.4826107420682773 -6.238217364811495 -1.966199265610444 -2.1624666424135977 2.014861831075435 4.143056495983624e-7 0.999901341448654 0.16812145388254565 0.5889709108552483 0.4212141706080315 0.24284481424824048 -0.03505188961118154 -0.16940390920534412 1.0];

tspan = (0.0,endd);
prob = ODEProblem(f,ICs,tspan);
function dmnCheck(u,p,t)
    return u[1] > 200.0 || u[1] < -200.0 
end
integ = init(prob,Tsit5(),maxiters=1e10,isoutofdomain=dmnCheck);
solve!(integ)
```

Comment: What OS and how did you install julia?

Answer (score 1):

Running this code, I don't get a crash - after around 680 simulated seconds (2502 time steps) there's a detected instability and the solver aborts. At a first glance I'm not sure that this is a Julia issue. Plotting the system of equations most of the variables are nearly flat lines, so the derivatives will be extremely close to zero.

There are some helpful suggestions here: https://docs.sciml.ai/DiffEqDocs/stable/basics/faq/. But as the page states, "99.99% of the time this has been debugged, it has turned out to be an error in the user's model." So I'd start by triple checking those equations are right.